# AJAX POST not loading class on button click.

Tags: php, ajax

If rating = +0 the following will show (standby).

[image]

If I click on the button, then the following will show( adding rating ).

[image]

If I click again, then the following will show ( removing rating )

[image]

---

I'd like for it to show as follows:

if rating = +0, when I click it the following will show.

[image]

**Issue:** When I click the button the font-weight:bold & color: # goes away when It should automatically update with the class. What am I doing wrong? Sorry for this lame question, just been at it for a while and I'm stuck with such a simple problem I'm sure.

This is my code:

PHP :

```
<div class="up vote" name="voteUp" id="<?php echo $post_iD;?>">
    <div class="wrapper">+<?php echo $VoteRate;?></div>
</div>
```

AJAX:

```
$(function()
{
    $(".vote").click(function()
    {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var name = $(this).attr("name");
        var dataString = 'id='+ id ;
        var parent = $(this);

        if (name=='voteUp')
        {
            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "voting/up_vote.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html)
                {
                    parent.html(html);
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: just a note. if you are using jquery above than 1.7.2 then `success` is deprecated. use `.done()` instead.

Comment: That I did not now, I'm using the latest.. 1.10.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your success function, replace the HTML of the `.wrapper` div, not the parent:

```
parent.find(".wrapper").html(html);
```

Comment: isn't $(".wrapper",this) ??

Comment: `this` would refer to the AJAX success function.

Comment: really? i think it was poiting to $('.vote') node, cuz its is on click function. but not sure. if "this" on that context will poiting to ajax success function, so you'r right.

Comment: No, he's correct I should have added the .wrapper instead of the parent. It has worked.

Comment: @iBrazilian -- Awesome, glad to help! Be sure to mark it as answered as well.